# why does the sum of Infinite terms of GP doesn't converge for x>1

Tags: sequences-and-series

could anyone explain why the sum of infinite terms of GP doesn't converge for x>1.Is that because a negative number can't never be obtained when a sum of terms is added?

where $\sum_n^\infty(a^n)$=$\left(\frac a{1-r}\right)$

which is derived from: [ $a(\frac{1-r^n} {1-r})$ as $n\to\infty$ it becomes 
$\left(\frac a{1-r}\right)$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the general term of a converging series converges to $0$ and that, for every $|r|\ge1$, $|r^n|\ge1$ for every $n$, hence $r^n\to 0$ is impossible
(Taken from @Did 's comment)

Another way is
to
Notice that if
$$s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n ar^i$$
for $|r|\gt1$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}r^n=\infty$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=\infty$$

**Update:**

After OP's request I've decided to post this, actually there are some limitations of my plotting software but I hope following images help

Here$$f(x)=(1.01)^x$$
(Don't forget to notice scale)

[image]
[image]

Comment: the reason why I couldn't accept this answer is I couldn't get why $\lim_{n \to \infty}r^n=\infty$

Comment: really satisfied....

Comment: I was just studying Laplace Transform.Couldn't get why they have plugged exponential function into Laplace transform.

Comment: Two problems: "for $|r|\ge1$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}r^n=\infty$" This is not true for every $|r|\ge1$. // "$\lim_{n \to \infty}r^n=\infty\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=\infty$" The implication does not hold (even if you mean $+\infty$).

Comment: Yes this is a way out. Another, more powerful, option is to note that the general term of a converging series converges to $0$ and that, for every $|r|\geqslant1$, $|r^n|\geqslant1$ for every $n$, hence $r^n\to0$ is impossible.

Comment: @I've edited my answer. Thanks!